# How can I hotlink/embed a Twitpic image?

Tags: api, twitter, twitpic

So in this URL: http://twitpic.com/2paihn

The Twitpic ID is: 2paihn

And the actual image URL is: 
http://s3.amazonaws.com/twitpic/photos/large/163413275.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=0ZRYP5X5F6FSMBCCSE82&Expires=1284740401&Signature=6lgT6ruyyUDDjLOB7d42XABoCLU%3D

I've tried getting the integer id through the api (i.e. 163413275) and replacing it in the s3.amazon.com url, but this seems to only work some of the time. Most of the time I get an 'access denied' message when I request the amazon-hosted image.

Do you know of another hack to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `http://twitpic.com/show/thumb/<imageid>` to get a thumbnail version.

Answer (score 9):

This is the direct link to the image:
http://twitpic.com/show/full/2paihn
You can use it in an img tag or link it. It will forward to the amazon S3 url with a new expiration date and signature so whoever you're showing it to won't get the access denied message.

Source: http://dev.twitpic.com/docs/thumbnails/